# My browsersync server refreshes the page but with old content

Tags: gulp, browserify, browser-sync

## What I want

I want to setup gulp to bundle my files as I make changes to source code and reload the browser automatically.

I use `browser-sync` as my development server,  `browserify` to bundle my javascript files and `gulp` as my task runner.

## What's the problem

It worked at first, but now when I save source file, browser is reloaded, but the old code is loaded and the change is not reflected. I need to refresh the browser manually.

I blame factor-bundle browserify plugin, which basically splits the bundle into 3 bundles - A, B and Common (index.js, tests.js and app.js in my case where the actual app code is in app.js).

## What I have so far

gulpfile.js [relevant code only]:

*the critical code is `bundleTypescript` function*

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var watchify = require("watchify");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var tsify = require("tsify");
var gutil = require("gulp-util");
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var merge = require('merge-stream');

var paths = {
  entryPoint: "src/index.ts",
  tests: "src/tests.ts",
  distDir: "./dist/",
};

var config = {
  externalModules: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-bootstrap']
};


gulp.task('default', ['watch-typescript'], function () {
  devServer();
});

function devServer() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: paths.distDir,
  });
}


var bundler = browserify({
  basedir: '.',
  debug: true,
  entries: [paths.entryPoint, paths.tests]
}).plugin(tsify); //can be replaced by watchify in watch-typescript
bundler.external(config.externalModules);

gulp.task("watch-typescript", function () {
  var watchedBrowserify = watchify(bundler);
  watchedBrowserify.on("update", function () { return bundleTypescript(true); });
  watchedBrowserify.on("log", gutil.log);
  bundler = watchedBrowserify;
});

function bundleTypescript(isDebug) {
  var indexStream = source("index.js");
  var testStream = source("tests.js");
  bundler.plugin('factor-bundle', { outputs: [indexStream, testStream] });

  var appStream = bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'));


  return merge(appStream, indexStream, testStream)
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ debug: true, loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDir + 'scripts')) //output
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()); //refresh browser
}
```

full gulp file can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/4ajba1nx/

**Why the changes are not reflected when browsersync reloads the browser**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that this question was posted some days ago. But anyways I will try to answer it in case you still couldn't solve the issue, or maybe it can help somebody else who is facing a similar problem.

I suspect that the problem is coming from this line of code:

```
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

It was put in the wrong order of the stream pipeline. What happens is that BrowserSync receives and streams the output of the previous line which is gulp.dest().

I suggest to move it after this line:

```
merge(appStream, indexStream, testStream)
```

The result will be:

```
merge(appStream, indexStream, testStream)
  .pipe(browserSync.stream())
```

Which means after the 3 bundles are merged the result will be piped to BrowserSync which will stream it to the browser.

Here you can find a Boilerplate project which combines Gulp + Browserfy + BrowserSync with CSS inject: https://github.com/anass-b/Gulp_Browserfy_BrowserSync

Comment: I can't tell you how much this helped me!  Most discussions on this problem are regarding the code to trigger the reload.  Placement is key!  I had my pipe at the very end of the sass task and it was the sourcemaps preceding it that was my issue.  After moving my reload pipe directly below my minify pipe, it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisDay I'm glad it helped.